# React useState changes my constant initial state

Tags: reactjs, use-state

My `selectItem` event changes my `initialState` which I intentionally implemented to stay as a constant.

> Panel.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Panel.css";
import Item from "./Item";

const initialState = [
  { text: 1, isSelected: false },
  { text: 2, isSelected: false },
  { text: 3, isSelected: false },
  { text: 4, isSelected: false },
  { text: 5, isSelected: false }
];

export default function Panel() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialState);

  const selectItem = k => {
    console.log(k);
    const updatedItems = [...initialState];
    updatedItems.find(item => item.text === k).isSelected = true;
    setItems(updatedItems);
  };

  return (
    <div className="Panel">
      {items.map(item => (
        <Item
          key={item.text}
          text={item.text}
          isSelected={item.isSelected}
          clicked={selectItem}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Item.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Item.css";

export default function Item({ text, isSelected, clicked }) {
  return (
    <div className="Item" onClick={() => clicked(text)}>
      {isSelected ? <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>{text}</div> : text}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at it this way, your array is an array of objects, and each index (item) is a reference to some specific object.

Basically when you are creating the `updatedItems` array, you are spreading all of its references into a new "array that is referencing objects." So, technically, you are using the very same objects. Once you select one and mutate it, you are mutating the object which both `initialState` and `items` are referencing.

What you are doing is a shallow clone (copy) of the array.

If you wish to do a deep clone, a simple method would be to do: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState))`.

You can also use utilities like lodash/cloneDeep https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep

Keep in mind though, that deep cloning can also be very expensive and not always the desired result.

Comment: As a method to avoid this, I would also suggest using a library like [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) to avoid changing the state directly

Comment: I think this answer explains it very well. Just wanted to add that the `const` keyword in javascript does **not** make the object/array immutable. It just prevents reassignment.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line that reads ...

`const updatedItems = [...initialState];`

to ...

`const updatedItems = [...items];`

The `initialState` const should only be used to initialize the `items` state value.

[Sandbox ...](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-sea-1n3qm?file=/src/Panel.js)